# rails model returns nilClass although it contains data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `send` method inside `destinations_group_controller`.

```
def send
  @destinations_group = DestinationsGroup.all
  puts @destination_group.class      #prints NilClass
  redirect_to destinations_groups_path
end
```

`DestinationsGroup.all` returns NilClass although the data exist. I checked in ruby console and it returns:

> ActiveRecord::Relation [#< DestinationsGroup id: 1, title: ...>

any ideas why i cannot get this data from code?

Comment: Restart your dev server, put debugger inside send and paste please what is returned for `DestinationsGroup.class` and `DestinationsGroup.all`. Also please paste your `DestinationGroup` model filename and code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a typo (@destinations_group instead of @destination_group):

```
puts @destinations_group.class      #prints NilClass
```